# How to add a block in magento

Tags: php, magento, block, addition

I am working on a magento theme but stuck with adding social links in header.
 I just want to put three Social links on to my site in header section of every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on the template your using.
The file you'll need to edit will more than likely be in /APP/DESIGN/Somehwere  . The somewhere will depend on you the theme you're using.

To see which file you need to edit, turn on template hints:  From your admin panel, go to System >> Configuration >> Developer

Depending on your setup, you may have to set it for your default view or a specific store view.

A quick tutorial of template hints is here : http://www.westwideweb.com/wp/2009/08/04/magento-how-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-and-inline-translation/

Answer (score 2):

The base header template is located in:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

But it's not good practice to directly edit this file, while you can do so.

The proper way would be to make a new theme folder, setup your store to use the right theme within admin then to edit the header.phtml file from that theme, which will override the default base theme - eg:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/yourtheme/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

Comment: make sure your cache is disabled too

Answer (score 2):

make template path hints on for your store view. System->Configuration->Developer. (You can use your specific IP in allowed IPs not to effect the view)

Disable the cache.

Refresh the home page.

You can view the file there, go to that file.

You can directly add it there or you can create a static block and use that in your phtml file according to your wish.

Comment: what problem you are getting, are you able to see the file name and please confirm that you dont have any cache mechanism installed.